# How to create a directory in "src" directory in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, directory-structure

When I create a new project using Dynamic Web Application template, it creates following structure, src -> main -> webapp -> WEB-INF, and there is option to create a directory inside src folder as shown in the following image.

[image]

However when I create a project without using a template, then it does not allow to create any directory inside src folder. There is no option to create directory inside src as shown in the following image.

**How can I create same directory structure as above using an empty project?**

[image]

Comment: don't create a directory in there, create packages

Comment: That's simply because IntelliJ recognizes the src as being a source folder of a Java project. If you simply want a directory, you can create a package (it is a directory concretely). But what is your actual point of doing that if not adding source files (.java)?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I'm trying to create same structure as Intellij creates in first screenshot, ie. to create a java file in src -> main -> webapp folder.

Comment: Can you show what is already inside "src" (by collapsing the content using the little arrow on the left of the word "src")?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ maybe there was some file that i created, but that doesn't make any difference. Here is new project screenshot where src folder is empty. https://i.imgur.com/bgn110K.png In the menu there is no option to create directory (it is available if I create project using web app template as seen in first image)

Comment: In the first menu, the second last option is "Mark directory as". You should select "Unmark as source root" and the directory will return back to normal. Then you will be able to create your structure again. Currently it's blue, meaning IntelliJ consider it as a source root, and if it's a source root you're not supposed to add directories inside, but packages (which happen to be directory but you confuse intellij with this setup)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new Package instead. It is basically the same and also creates a new directory inside your project folder

Answer (score 0):

Change the view from project view to packages view. when you change that you will get the directory option

[image: Like this]